# Publishing versions out of order

Tags: release-management, semantic-versioning, npm

Does npm allow you to publish *earlier* versions of a package? The only documentation I could find was on [npm’s site](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/publish):

> [npm-publish] Fails if the package name and version combination already exists in the specified registry.
>
> Once a package is published with a given name and version, that specific name and version combination can never be used again…

So by these specs, could I theoretically publish `v3.2.0-beta` *before* publishing `v3.1.0`, as long as none of those name–version combinations already exist? (I assume the answer is “yes,” but you never know if the author left out what they considered obvious: that version numbers should only increase.)

This is the reason I ask. My current latest version is `v3.1.0-beta`, and I’ve been doing work on my development branch ever since that release. But now I’m at a point where v3.2 is **feature-locked**, that is, no new features are to be added. So I feel like it’s time to go ahead and publish `v3.2.0-beta` and start testing for bugs. However, `v3.1.0` (stable) hasn’t been published yet, and I don’t want to wait until that release to publish my beta of v3.2.

So essentially, am I free to publish `v3.2.0-beta` now, even though v3.1 is still in beta, and then next week, would I still be able to publish `v3.1.0` even though it is has a lower version number? Or will npm report an error if I attempt to do so?

Can you point to any examples of packages that have done this? And which version does the `latest` tag point to: the most recent, or the most precedent (having the highest precedence)?

Comment: Yes, otherwise there'd be no way to publish bugfixes for versions that have otherwise been superseded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. As johnrsharpe mentioned, this allows you to publish bugfixes on old versions, *as well* as concurrently release multiple testing versions.

Which is considered `latest`? From [`npm publish`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/publish):

> `[--tag <tag>]` Registers the published package with the given tag, such
>   that npm install `<name>@<tag>` will install this version. By default,
>   npm publish updates and npm install installs the latest tag.

So, to publish the `v3.1.0` as `latest`, just check out that branch and `npm publish`. Omitting `--tag` will set it to `latest`.

To make `v3.2.0-beta` available, use `npm publish --tag beta`.

In npm land, it's common to apply `--tag next` for upcoming releases that will become the next stable version. So you could tag your v3.2.0 as "next" so that developers who like the bleeding edge can prepare for *that* becoming "latest".

See [dist-tag](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dist-tag) for more, especially [what tags are for](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dist-tag#purpose).

To your point "that version numbers should only increase", since [semver](http://semver.org/) allows a (basically) arbitrary string to follow the patch version number to, there is no way to know which the author considers "before" between `1.0.0-beta` and `1.0.0+exp.sha.5114f85`, for example.